# Create empty array and add value causes "Array index is out of range"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, initialization

What is wrong here?

```
string[] keysDictionary = new string[]{};
keysDictionary [0] = "test";
```

I get

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>   Array index is out of range.

Comment: Because that is an array with 0 of length, you should do `new string[length]`

Comment: Do I need the length? Or can I create an empty array and add later values to it (I don't know how many values before)?

Comment: @testing In that case you need List<string> not array

Comment: You should look into using [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's an array-like structure that allows the addition of more elements.

Comment: I were too much in `php`. Here you can do this.

Comment: An array is fixed size. Maybe you want to use a `List<string>`.

Comment: Can I use and index when working with `List<string>`?

Comment: @testing yes you can use an index with `List<string>`, `MyList[3]` or similar.

Comment: @testing, even though `C#` is a high level language it still has some very basic constructs, like fixed arrays which you are trying to use. Only use arrays (ie ´type[]´ syntax like `int[]`) when you create a fixed collection you are going to be iterating over many times. In my opinion, for all other cases the performance gain is not worth the hassle of keeping track of the array size manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add anything to a 0 length array. You are essentially trying to set the value of the first element of an array with no elements.  Use something like a list instead if you want to do this, arrays cannot be resized.

```
var keysDictionary = new List<string>();
keysDictionary.Add("test");
```

Comment: How can this answer have upvotes when it won't even compile due to the typo in line 2?

Comment: Because it is just a typo.  Answer is already clear without compiling.

Answer (score 6):

By stating {} you are defining this as an empty array.

Thus you should either define the size as:

```
string[] keysDictionary = new string[1];
keysDictionary [0] = "test";
```

Or

Initialize like this:

```
string[] keysDictionary = new string[]{"test"};
```

Answer (score 2):

`new string[]{}` creates zero-length array

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the size of the array.

e.g.

```
string[] keysDictionary = new string[1];
keysDictionary [0] = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Array that dynamically changes size when you add values use a List instead.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a bit .net 1.1, more commonly you would use `List<T>`

Comment: Sorry I'm too used to Java I just assumed C# had a similar feature

Comment: using Arraylist is not recommended from the moment of generics implementation in c#